# Workflow Rule (Ischanged) - Field is not updated when the record is created

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update, workflowrule

I've created a workflow rule that will update a field when a record is created or edit. However, the workflow rule is not updating the field when the record is created, just when the record is updated. I need this field update when the record is created as well.

My formula:

```
AND(OR(ISCHANGED( BillingPostalCode ),
    ISCHANGED( FirstName ),
ISCHANGED( LastName )))
```

What's wrong in the formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, aside from the `AND` being extraneous, you need to add an `ISNEW` check to your `OR` clause if you want it to fire on create. The `ISCHANGED` formula returns false on create.

```
OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Field1), ISCHANGED(Field2), ISCHANGED(etc))
```